# IntelliJ IDE (Rider, Android Studio...) - how to hide "usage" links above properties/methods/etc

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, settings, rider, jetbrains-rider

IntelliJ Rider IDE version 2022.1:
Above class properties or methods I have this link called **"usages"**.

**How do I turn the "**usages**"-link off?**

They are driving me crazy. I don't know what these things are called, so googling didn't give me any results. I glanced through myriad of settings in the IntelliJ Settings window - also no idea.

[image: screenshot with usage links]

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can hide all metrics by disabling "Code Vision" (CTRL+SHIFT+A + `code vision` for a quick access in the settings).

You can also hide specific metrics by right clicking on it.

[image]

It is also possible to toggle the hints globally with the action `Toggle Inlay Hints Globally` (accessible with CTRL+SHIT+A + `Toggle Inlay`)

[image]

You can also assign a shortcut to this action.

Comment: Thanks, would have never guessed it.

Comment: File -> Preferences -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Code vision and uncheck "Usages" for the Intellij folk that get directed here.

Comment: Thank you - would have never figured out that the "Usage" is a clickable text.

Comment: I find this intrusive - there must another way to quickly show usage via hover/click

Comment: I edited the answer with information about an action that might be what you are looking for @jimsmith

Comment: Had to un-toggle and toggle

Comment: Thanks this is great. What a crappy IDE feature.

Answer (score 1):

In a windows machine. File->Settings->(Search code vision)->remove tick of Usages. Also you can remove other code visions if you want. Recommended to keep the tick of Related problems. (short cut key for settings - Ctrl+Alt+S).

Answer (score 1):

For the latest android studio dolphine.File->Settings->Inlay Hints->Code Hints(remove tick)