# Removal of "usages"-links in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, settings

While changing PCs I downloaded the latest version of IntelliJ (2022.1.2 Build #IU-221.5787.30) and I can now see **"usages"-links** for all fields, methods and such in my code.

It does seem to work as it is supposed to, but I find that it takes up too much space.
**How can I turn the "usages"-links off?**

[image: Picture of usage links on class and fields]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928162/rider-ide-how-to-hide-usage-links-above-properties-methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ Rider IDE - how to hide "usage" links above properties/methods/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928162/intellij-rider-ide-how-to-hide-usage-links-above-properties-methods-etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the appropriate checkbox in settings: **Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints > Code Vision > Usages**:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA settings]