# What is this padding after class names, comments, and functions in Android Studio editor

Tags: android-studio

On Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 I see a phantom margin before functions, after methods and comments, those lines are magical and confusing, in the image we can see it between lines 11 and 12.

Does anyone knows how may I disable that ?

[image: sample]

thanks

I can't see anything that makes sense in the settings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ IDE (Rider, Android Studio...) - how to hide "usage" links above properties/methods/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928162/intellij-ide-rider-android-studio-how-to-hide-usage-links-above-proper)

Comment: I think it is the version  control plug-in